# babel-plugin-preprocessor not working in React 18 with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I want to use the babel-plugin-preprocessor to remove console.log() calls from my React application. My application was created using create-react-app and uses Typescript.

I'm following the instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-preprocessor. I installed the pluging:

```
npm install -D babel-plugin-preprocessor
```

I added the file babel.config.json to the root of my project, and it has the following contents:

```
{
"plugins" : [
["preprocessor", {
  "symbols": { "IS_BROWSER": false },
  "directives": { "DEBUG": false }
}]
  ]
  }
```

The above comes directly from the website, but I've set the two values "false" instead of the default "true" because I want to see the console.log lines removed. The website says to put the above in "the babel configuration file," I'm assuming that means to add a file named babel.config.json to my project root based on this babel page: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration

I then add the following to a *.tsx file in my project:

```
// #if IS_BROWSER
console.log('Home.tsx IS_BROWSER is true');
// #else
console.log('Home.tsx IS_BROWSER is not true');
```

I then launch the project on my local host using npm-start. But both lines get printed to my console. I was only expecting the 2nd line to get printed; I expected the first line to be removed.

What am I missing? I'm just assuming that the existence of babel.config.json in my project root will magically make all of this work, but obviously this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

CreateReactApp is not respecting .babelrc file **directly** as you expect.
CreateReactApp has it's built-in babel config, so both .babelrc and babel in package.json will be ignored.

There are over two ways to control CreateReactApp.

1. CreateReactApp native commander [**npm run eject**.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-eject)
   This commander will unzip build-in config to project path, and then you can control it.
2. [craco](https://craco.js.org/) Create React App Configuration Override, an easy and comprehensible configuration layer for create-react-app. [Babel override](https://craco.js.org/docs/configuration/babel/)

**Once you eject, you can’t go back!**

And then you can add your babel config into package.json, like this:

```
 "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "preprocessor",
        {
          "symbols": {
            "IS_BROWSER": true
          },
          "directives": {
            "DEBUG": true
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
```

And your code will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks @YinPeng.Wei. I'm not completely sure what you mean. Are you saying I don't need a separate babal.config.json, and instead I should add the above into my package.json?

Comment: I have re-edited my answer to a clear explanation.